# how to create listview that expand and shrink?

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

In my application i have listview with plus & minus button on plus button click listview should expand and on minus button click it should shrink. I have done this with the following code :

```
if (isChecked) {
     objectsOrder.get(getPosition).setSelected(
     buttonView.isChecked());
     holder.details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     holder.iorder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
     objectsOrder.get(getPosition).setSelected(false);
     holder.details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     holder.iorder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

but my need is user can able to open single link suppose the user try to click other one the previous one should shrink before open new one. how to do this?? I hope you got my problem

pls give a suggestion thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you directly use Expandable list-view. It will do exactly what you want.

Comment: in my application action should happen only on plus or minus button click not list items click

Answer (score 4):

Use this in mainactivity

```
ListView gv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
gv.setAdapter(new TextAdapter());
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

                    View toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

                    // Creating the expand animation for the item
                    ExpandAnimation expandAni = new ExpandAnimation(toolbar, 500);

                    // Start the animation on the toolbar
                    toolbar.startAnimation(expandAni);
                }
            });             
        }
    });
```

This in your Listview adapter class

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    <-- your codes -->

  View toolbar = convertView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin = -50;
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return convertView;
```

Listview adapter xml file

```
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_marginBottom="-50dip"
      android:visibility="gone"
      android:layout_height="50dip"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/doSomething1"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Harder"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/doSomething2"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Better"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/doSomething3"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="Faster"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/doSomething4"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="Stronger"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is ExpandAnimation class

```
public class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
private View mAnimatedView;
private LayoutParams mViewLayoutParams;
private int mMarginStart, mMarginEnd;
private boolean mIsVisibleAfter = false;
private boolean mWasEndedAlready = false;


public ExpandAnimation(View view, int duration) {

    setDuration(duration);
    mAnimatedView = view;
    mViewLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

    // decide to show or hide the view
    mIsVisibleAfter = (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);

    mMarginStart = mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
    mMarginEnd = (mMarginStart == 0 ? (0- view.getHeight()) : 0);

    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

    if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {

        // Calculating the new bottom margin, and setting it
        mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginStart
                + (int) ((mMarginEnd - mMarginStart) * interpolatedTime);

        // Invalidating the layout, making us seeing the changes we made
        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

    // Making sure we didn't run the ending before (it happens!)
    } else if (!mWasEndedAlready) {
        mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginEnd;
        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

        if (mIsVisibleAfter) {
            mAnimatedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        mWasEndedAlready = true;
    }
}}
```

This will help u to make Listview to expandable Listview